# How to not resolve url() with Dart Sass in Webpack encore?

Tags: url, sass, resolve, webpack-encore

I just switched from `node-sass` to `sass` (Dart Sass) to compile my scss files to css.
I use Symfony's Webpack Encore, and I have `enableSassLoader()` in my webpack.config.js with no specific config.

With `node-sass` I could use `url()` css property with an url pointing to the public folder

```scss
.myClass {
  background: url('/path/inside/public-folder/img.png')
}
```

And it worked perfectly.

But now with `sass`, when I build my app, I got an error message because `sass` tries to resolve the path inside my assets files, that I do not want, and I can't find a way to tell `sass`: Do not resolve path in url() in my scss.

Any idea how to achieve this?
Maybe some options to pass to `enableSassLoader()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found how to no resolve urls, it was not in `enableSassLoader`, but in `configureCssLoader` in webpack.config.js:

```js
.configureCssLoader((options) => {
  options.url = false
})
```